# show all equals

Tags: math-operators

I'd like to show that for some function `C`, if `x_1 = x_2 = \ldots = x_n` then

```
\[C(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i) = C(x_1) = C(x_2) = \ldots = C(x_n)\]
```

is there a way to do this with a single big equals sign just like the sum?

Comment: Could you please add a little more description of what you're looking for? In case it would help, you could add an image which could be even drawn by hand...

Comment: Equating is not an operation but an assignment (a relation). A big equal sign is going to be a wrong notation if you wish to use it as *equate everything under this symbol*.

Comment: Mathematical note: no notation for this exists.  Although this is not a problem, it is sort of a shame that there's no `\bigneq` symbol, as (an observation of one of my high school teachers) there is a difference between saying `x \neq y \neq z` and `x \neq y, y \neq z, x \neq z`.

Comment: The mathematics of your question puzzles me. If the `x_i` are all equal then their average equals each of them and your assertion is true by definition for any function `C`. If you remove the hypothesis that the `x_i` are all equal then your assertion for `n=2` says the value of `C` is the same for any three points `x`, `y` and `(x+y)/2`. That means `C` is a constant function. What am I missing?

Comment: the statement only holds if the hypothesis is true - I know it is an obvious point but it is part of a larger point I'm trying to make.  Since you are curious, if all `x_i` are different `C(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n C(x_i)`

Comment: More on the mathematics. So `C(average(x_i)) = average(C(x_i))`. In particular, for all `x` and `y`, `C((1/2)(x+y))=(1/2)(C(x)+C(y))`. If `C` is differentiable, differentiate with respect to `x`. Then (simplifying) `C'((1/2)(x+y))= C'(x)`, independent of `y`. So `C'` is constant, and `C` must be linear.

Comment: @RyanReich: As a result of the lack of `\bigneq`, I once wrote `|{a,b,c,d,e,f,g}| = 7` to express that `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f` and `g` are all different. I guess you could extend this idea to `|{a,b,c,d,e,f,g}| = 1` to express that they're all the same.

Comment: @JohnWickerson I was going to suggest that, but it's an obscure way of conveying an obvious concept.  You have to think too hard to figure out what part of the notation is significant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a suggestion.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}% change to your document class
\begin{document}
\[
C\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) = C(x_j) 
\]
where $j=1,\ldots,n$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, that probably is the clearest